# APNS sending multiple push notifications after reinstall of application

Tags: cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, appgyver

Our push service provider updated their libraries and this seems to have fixed the problem. As far as I understand it had to do with the handling of old tokens.

---

Our Appgyver / Cordova application is receiving multiple push notifications from APNS (and GCM) after a reinstall of the app.

This seems like an issue that we have not seen before, our iOS app would receive **over 50 messages** when reinstalled that many times (by reinstall I mean completely remove the app and installing it again from an external source).

Each reinstall, it looks like the application remembers the old push tokens, so we keep getting more and more notifications. This is very strange, as I though Apple notified itself after each uninstall to reject the push token. We've got the same problem with Android.

**Plugin:**
https://github.com/AppGyver/PushNotifications

**Push provider:**
Azure Cloud

I almost cannot believe it's possible to push bomb an Apple device like that and we have no idea what could be the cause here. Has anyone experienced something like this before?

Thanks in advance for any help / advice you can give.

**Extra notes:**

- This happens on iOS and Android devices
- I can't recall this happening to our app before, so I think it's a recent issue
- Every time we open the app, we call the register function through JS (as recommended by the APNS service)
- This topic has a similiar issue, but this can't lead to over 50 push messages right? [iOS push notifications behavior when app is deleted and then reinstalled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858224/ios-push-notifications-behavior-when-app-is-deleted-and-then-reinstalled)
- This readonly topic on the Apple message boards is reporting the same issue: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13414?q=multiple%20push

Comment: This seems strange are you using GCM topics to send messages to the client?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I did not see the notification.. But our push service provider updated their libraries and this seems to have fixed the problem. 

As far as I understand it had to do with the handling of old tokens. Thanks anyway :)